# Can a type be defined inside a template parameter list in C++?

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, language-lawyer

In the following definition of template `struct B`, a lambda is used as a default value of a non-type template argument, and in the body of the lambda some type `A` is defined:

```
template <auto = []{ struct A{}; }>
struct B {};
```

Clang and MSVC are fine with this definition, but GCC complains:

> error: definition of '`struct<lambda()>::A`' inside template parameter list

Demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/f1dxGbPvs

Which compiler is right here?

Comment: This should be fine. Defining a struct inside the lambda doesn't prevent it from being a literal type, which should be sufficient to allow it to be used as a non-type template parameter. Also, GCC's error message is suspect. It's the same message as you get when defining a type inside a template parameter list, which isn't allowed https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/9PdxG8jKE so I think this is likely GCC making a parse error.

Comment: gcc also accepts a freestanding lambda with a type definition in it: `auto l = []{ struct A{}; };` - So, a workaround: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/v1sfoqdMv

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[[temp.param]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.param#2) says:

> Types shall not be defined in a *template-parameter* declaration.

Taking this as written, GCC is correct to reject this code: this prohibition is not constrained to *type-id* of a type parameter, but applies to anywhere within template parameter declaration.  Including nested within a lambda.

This sentence was added as a result of [DR 1380](https://wg21.cmeerw.net/cwg/issue1380) ([N3481](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3481.html#1380)), which reveals it was considered already implied by what now I am guessing to be [[dcl.fct]/17](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct#17):

> Types shall not be defined in return or parameter types.

This, however, only seems to apply to the type of the parameter declared and not to the *initializer-clause*.

On the other hand, one might also read it as prohibiting lambdas themselves in template parameters.  After all, a lambda expression implicitly defines a class type ([[expr.prim.lambda.closure]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.lambda.closure#1)).

On the third hand, we also have [[expr.prim.lambda.closure]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.lambda.closure#2), which states:

> The closure type is declared in the smallest block scope, class scope, or namespace scope that contains the corresponding *lambda-expression*.

The relevant scope here seems to be the namespace scope.  This would imply the lambda should be treated as if its type were declared outside the template parameter list.  But then, so should be declarations inside the body of the lambda, and the definition in the question should be allowed.

Personally, I consider it a defect in the standard that the scope of this prohibition seems so ill-defined.

Comment: "*I would consider this a defect in the standard.*" Why is creating a named type just so unacceptable to C++ programmers these days? Is it really too much to ask to just give this type a name?

Comment: Don’t ask me. I presume the restriction was meant to prohibit things like `template <typename T = struct point { int x, y; }>`. I think it makes little sense in this context.